# PhpStorm: Автоматизация создания файлов

Tags: php, phpstorm

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане. На днях стал юзать PhpStorm. Скажите, можно ли в этой IDE выполнить следующую задачу:

Дано:
Некоторый фреймворк. Предположим, что для создания какого-нибудь компонента требуюся следующие файлы:

```
componentName - директория
  controller.php - логика компонента
  description.php - описание компонента. Шаблонный код с названием, назначением и версией компонента
  templates - директория
    templateName1 - директория
    view.php - представление компонента
```

Необходимо: написать собственный визард который бы:
1) Создавал вышеописанный каркас
2) Добавлял в указанные файлы, некоторые шаблонные куски кода.
3) Вызывался комбинацией горячих клавиш.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такого функционала не встречал. Обычно такое умеют сами фреймворки, по крайне мере популярные точно умеют.

Comment: Это какой такой фреймворк, сам создаст все файлы, и подготовит их к редактированию?? Ну ка просветите.

Comment: yii, sf, zf

Comment: @VasyOk я понял что вы о генерации кода. ясно понятно

Comment: Автору топика ничего не мешает расширить функционал фреймворка и сделать так, что бы он генерил кастомные файлы, для собственной архитектуры.

Comment: Дык, в том то и проблема. Попал в руки самопильный, велосипедный "фреймворк". По функционалу, невероятно далек от популярных, а перейти на новый, пока возможности нет ) Накатал несколько bash скриптиков, что бы они генерили нужные каркасы. Но захотелось, что бы было со всякими перделками и свистелками. Вот и подумал, что в phpstorm есть нечто подобное.